# Eclipse runs a full build in each save while working with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I converted my normal java projects to be maven projects, after this change I started to notice eclipse is running a full build in all the projects in the workspace in every save I do.

This is not comfortable for work, I expect the auto build in Eclipse to build only effected projects from the change and not all the workspace.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to disable the "Build Automatically" option in eclipse.

> By default, the Eclipse workbench is configured to build projects automatically. However you should disable this option, otherwise your entire project will be rebuilt whenever, for example, you save a change to your makefile or source files. Click Project > Build Automatically and ensure there is no checkmark beside the Build Automatically menu item.

[image]

**You can build your project using maven capability of eclipse**.

Select the project & right click→ Select Run as option → Select Maven Package option

Comment: But i want it to build automatically! only what it should and not all the projects that were not effected by my save

Comment: Then check this.In Project → Clean,  you should  select "Clean projects selected below", select your project and check "Start a build immediately" with "Build only selected projects".

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to do that, but.. if you insist:

<kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>Maven</kbd>

and disable the auto update (depends on the version of Eclipse you're using - you should have "offline" checkbox, just check it):

[image]

Edit: In order to build specific project, you should disable the automatic building, then close all projects you don't want to build.

Comment: I don't want to disable the auto update, what i expect to do is to configure eclipse to update/build only the effected projects and not all the workspace.

Comment: Sorry to say, but it didn't help :(
Both are selected in my enviroment, also I don't think it's the best solution to disable this options, the idea is simply to tell eclipse"build what it really needs a build" but it's building everything, which makes it very uncomfortable